# Desktop software to generate SEO reports

Tags: google-apps, reporting

I need a desktop software to generate software report for my clients at the end of every week. I do it manually at the moment and it takes me about 1.5 hours to compile the report.

I have tried IBP but the report it generates is too big and does not look very professional.

The critical parameters that should be considered by the software are:

- **Competetion Analysis** (basic analysis would be good - to see if they have moved up or down & if they've got any new links)
- **Positioning (in Google) for some pre-defined keywords**
- **Traffic change**

Anything else is not important but would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying the combination of [Pyscape](http://projects.benjaminestes.com/Pyscape/) and the [Mozscape API](http://apiwiki.moz.com/create-and-manage-your-account).

## Pyscape

- Free & Open Source
- Runs under python3.2+ which is also free & open source
- Produces CSV reports that you can then go on to customise, (hint python has lots of tools for manipulating CSV files and tools that can directly produce markdown or pdf files).
- Works with both free and paid Mozscape APIs

  ./pyscape.py bulk-metrics urls.txt -d out.csv

might produce:
[image: Screen Shot]

## Mozscape API

- Free and Paid access levels
- Metrics like MozRank, MozTrust, Domain Authority, and Page Authority

## Once you have your CSV file

*You can also use this approach if you already have a tool that can produce a CSV file*

- There are a huge selection of python CSV manipulation and analysis tools - take a look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).
- Personally I would look to create markdown output and then use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to produce whichever format you need to deliver.
- You can archive your CSV files to allow production of trends data, etc.